# FFMPEG permission denied trying to covert video

Tags: permissions, ffmpeg

This problem started for me on 18.04, and I tried to fix it then, unsuccessfully.  I've recently upgraded to 21.04 on a new hardware and the problem persists.

I installed ffmpeg 4.3.1 from the Ubuntu Software app
I also have installed Ubuntu restricted extras
Below is an example of a command that fails.  But even BASH scripts that worked before also fail with the same error.

```
~$ ffmpeg -i /mnt/Data/Videos/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi -ss 1 -t 95 /mnt/Data/Videos/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.mp4

/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-cuda --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnpp --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
/mnt/Data/Videos/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi: **Permission denied**
```

Comment: This looks like permissions on your share are not allowing you to either read or write to it.

Comment: Are you sure the paths are correct? It might be easier to `cd` into the document path and use a relative path instead of an absolute path

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ald /mnt/Data/Videos`.

Answer (score 6):

If file permissions look OK and you're still getting permission denied running ffmpeg, you should also check **where** ffmpeg is installed on your system by executing:

```
which ffmpeg
```

If you see

```
/snap/bin/ffmpeg
```

it means ffmpeg was installed using the snap package manager and that might be causing the permission denied error.

If that's the case, you can rectify the situation by permissioning ffmpeg to the proper snap resource by running (see [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580357/permission-denied-with-ffmpeg-via-snap-on-external-drive)):

```
sudo snap connect ffmpeg:removable-media
```

**NOTE:** this is due to a [security feature of the snap package manager](https://ubuntu.com/blog/security-corner-snap-interface-snap-connections).

Another workaround for someone who'd rather like to keep away from snap is to install ffmpeg using the apt package manager:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

and make sure you run ffmpeg installed by the apt package manager ( (apt will install into /usr/bin/) not the one installed by snap (snap installs into /snap/bin), that is by executing:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp3
```

And if you choose to install and use ffmpeg using the apt package manager, you might also want to remove ffmpeg installed through snap:

```
sudo snap remove ffmpeg
```

so that you don't get confused later about two ffmpeg installations on your system.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, run the following commands to fix the file not found error:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdrm-common
```

Whenever you get a file not found error, you can use `apt-file` to try and locate the package that provides the needed file.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search /usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids
```

It might take a while but it should return the following:

```
libdrm-common: /usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids
```

This is how I determined which package to install.

---

**Next**, it appears you don't have write permission on your mounted directory.

You can either remount the mounted filesystem with write permissions or you can copy the `.avi` file to your user's `$HOME` directory before you execute `ffmpeg`.

**For example**, you can copy the file to your user's Desktop directory:

```
cp /mnt/Data/Videos/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi $HOME/Desktop
```

and then run `ffmpeg` from there:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi -ss 1 -t 95 ~/Desktop/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.mp4
```

---

**If you still get a permission denied error**, you can change ownership of the file:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/Desktop/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi
```

and then try again:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi -ss 1 -t 95 ~/Desktop/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.mp4
```

Comment: I previously posted that I changed permissions and it worked.  But did not realize that I was in the wrong terminal window. 

It did work running ffmpeg under my Desktop directory.

Comment: I previously posted that I changed permissions and it worked.  But did not realize that I was in the wrong terminal window. 

It did work running ffmpeg under my Desktop directory.  But not under /mnt/Data/Videos

I tried running 
`sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /mnt/Data`

and that appears to have updated permissions, but ffmpeg still gives the same error
The current permissions are:
westcork@BlackUnicorn:~$ ls -ald /mnt/Data/Videos
drwxrwxr-x 30 westcork westcork 4096 May 22 16:35 /mnt/Data/Videos

At this point, I have a work around, which is great.  So thank you.

Comment: @Westcork Hmmm, what about `ls -la /mnt/Data/Videos/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi`

Comment: @Westcork Also for a script, it should be possible to output `ffmpeg` to a writable directory or to a temporary directory under `$HOME` and then copy the new file back to the original directory under `/mnt/Data/Videos/` to overwrite the old file. That is, if you can copy back without a permission denied error.

Comment: @Westcork Also, it's a stretch but you could also try setting the current user uid an gid with the mount command to double verify permissions. First, get your current user's uid and gid using the following command: `id`. Then, for example, let's say the uid is 1001 and the gid is 1001, you could run `sudo mount -o remount,rw,uid=1001,gid=1001 /dev/sda1 /mnt/Data`

Comment: @Westcork However, this will fail if the filesystem is ext4. In this case, you can chown the directory but you must do so recursively. `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/Data/Videos` and the following command may be necessary as well: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/Data/Videos/*`

Comment: @mchild  Here you go:  
westcork@BlackUnicorn:~$ ls -la /mnt/Data/Videos/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 westcork westcork 69631488 May 22 07:19 /mnt/Data/Videos/192.168.1.2_Street_main_20210522141323_141716-5fnd662.avi